# Windows 10 says bluetooth headphones are connected but also not connected

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

This is one of those nightmare issues where it seems to only be a problem between one computer and one device. The headphones connect just fine on other windows 10 machines, and other bluetooth headphones connect just fine to this computer.

Details:

Upon adding the device in bluetooth, windows says the headphones are connected, but the headphones do not indicate they are connected. The headphones are listed with three separate entries in the bluetooth settings window, under input devices, audio, and unspecified, but this is also the case on the computer where the headphones work just fine. In playback devices, the headphones are listed, but show as disconnected. Selecting "connect" does nothing.

In Devices and printers, the headphones show as connected and troubleshooter finds no problems. If the devices were paired by selecting the available devices listing that the headphone instructions say to select, the right-click menu does not show the "control" option. If paired by selecting the other listing, the control option will be there, but the only option will be to use the device as a proximity lock. Also pairing this way will cause the default windows 10 bluetooth settings window to minimize instantly whenever opened until the device is removed.

Steps already taken:

Used both device manager and a driver utility to check for for driver updates, uninstalled bluetooth devices and drivers and reinstalled, ran sfc /scannow, restarted pc and re-paired headphones numerous times.

Comment: Does it appear at all in the speaker settings/mixer? You might have to switch to using those headphones explicitly as a default.

Comment: Any luck?  Did you figure this out?